# Get records between by range in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table with fields like firstname, lastname and of course age where age value will be automatically populated since I have a function in the controller that would calculate age based on date birthday and current year.Now I want get data on a table based on a query a dynamic query, with age as the parameters

In database, I have a people table with  fields like so

```
name   lastname   age
john   simons     40
olivia newtin     100
sylvia gay        390
```

Now I want to get people who's age is from 40 to 100. Of course I am expecting john simons and olivia newtin will be the value returned.But I am getting null. How would you solve this?

controller

```
public function getAllPeopleByThisAge()
{
   //query to repository
    $min = 40;
    $max =  100
    $somereturn = $this->student->getAllPeopleByThisAge($min, $max);
}
```

Now somewhere in my repository

```
   public function getAllPeopleByThisAge($min,$max)
   {
      $this->people = DB::table('students')
                    ->select('students.age')
                    ->whereBetween('age',[$min, $max])
                    ->get();
   }
```

My databases show columns with age saved as integer.e.g 15, 20, 100 , 70.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `select('students.age')` it will return a list of user ages and then you call `->whereBetween('age',[$min, $max])->get();` of course it will return `null` as there is no field `age` on your query result of `select('students.age')`. Try to remove `select('students.age')` and leave everything after that,

```
DB::table('students')->whereBetween('age',[$min, $max])->get();
```